# How do I auto capitalize the content of a text-field in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I need a `v-text-field` where the user can input the confirmation code they received via SMS. The contents of this field should all be automatically turned into uppercase letters even if the user did not have the intent to write uppercase letters.

Comment: `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Where do I have to write .toUpperCase()? It doesn't work inside the tag as an attribute. Could you provide a sample code please?

Comment: I get this error: _'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS_

Comment: Sorry, that is true, we should append only the key of the object returned by `data()` function, meaning we can not append that function. ...will try to think about it later

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `keyup` event to uppercase like this:

```
<v-text-field v-model="code" label="Code" @keyup="uppercase" class="code"></v-text-field>

...

data: function() {
    return {
        code: ""
    };
},
methods: {
    uppercase() {
        this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ysemeniuk/pen/aboKmoQ)

Also additional CSS styling used to hide transformation delay from user

Comment: I had a similar problem, however the above code is pretty complex imo. Something like this might be much cleaner.

`
<v-text-field v-model="code" label="Code" @input="code = code.toUpperCase()" class="code"></v-text-field>
`
This removes the need for a single use method to be defined, and also don't have any input latency where the input first appears lower case and then is capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative is use the `input event`:

check this example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({msg: ''})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-text-field
    v-model="msg"
    placeholder="insert some text"
    label="convert on Blur"
    @input="msg = msg.toUpperCase()"/>
</div>
```

Check the official doc:

> https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#events-input

Comment: This works better. Text is immediately transformed. There is no lag.

Answer (score -3):

It's simply with `class="text-capitalize"`
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#transform